# Eclipse keeps setting incorrect repository root

Tags: eclipse, svn, repository, eclipse-3.6, helios

I have a project here:

svn+ssh://svn@example.com/folder/ProjectName

The repository root is svn+ssh://svn@example.com/folder

No matter how many times or how many ways I try checking out ProjectName, eclipse always helpfully tells me that the repository root is svn+ssh://svn@example.com.

I have another project in another repository:

svn+ssh://svn@example.com/repos/OtherProject

Eclipse correctly identifies the repository root as svn+ssh://svn@example.com/repos/

What settings, either in the svn repository or in Eclipse, would account for the discrepancy?

I am using JavaHL (JNI) and Eclipse Helios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution , via an obscure mailing list post:
http://svn.haxx.se/subusers/archive-2005-10/0103.shtml

> Actually, the information is stored in
>   the workspace folders
>   .metadata/.plugins/org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core
>   and
>   org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.ui. I
>   do not recommend to modify these
>   files, because some have binary
>   information. Instead, you could try to
>   delete the files (or save at another
>   location). Eclipse will then know
>   nothing about SVN locations. You can
>   then enter your correct repository
>   again. It should map the existing
>   projects to the new location.

I ran `

```
rm -rf workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.*
```

and that did the trick!